# LDAP. Spring Application without Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap, windows-server-2012-r2

I have Spring Boot application what is working with LDAP Autentication. Everythink is okay it is working but with asking username and password like a regular Spring security autentication with username and password. In Back it check username and password with ldap and if they are matched and decides autentication is true or not. Is it possible without asking username and password it can directly decides autentication is true or not because user already logged in his/her computer. And in my stiuation user have to log in twice and it not look me good solution.

My server version Microsoft Windows Server 2012R2. And Spring Boot version is 1.5.15.

Answer (score 1):

If the workstation logon produces a Kerberos token and your application is on the same network as the directory, [Spring Security Kerberos](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-kerberos#learn) would use the token to authenticate the user without requiring credentials to be entered.

If your application is external to the logon directory's network, [use an identity provider](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x/reference/html/chapter-idp-guide.html) to provide "single sign-on" functionality. ADFS, if the workstations are logged into a Windows domain, can authenticate users without requiring credentials to be entered *but* will also prompt for credentials when accessed from a machine that *isn't* already logged into the domain.

Comment: I will explore about  Spring Security Kerberos. Because it is suitable for my situation . Thank you very much for suggestion.